# I need bounce effect with CSS same as in powerpoint 365

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, powerpoint, keyframe

I need bounce animation with css. It will look like same as bounce effect in powerpoint 365. Object will bounce like a ball from left side to right

Comment: You can use [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Comment: no. i need custom css to create this effect

Comment: `animate.css` is opensource, just copy code

Comment: have not same effect as i need

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you could achieve this with a complex, but do-able `keyframes` animation. With an `on:hover` set like this: `element1:hover {animation: name | duration | ease-type | iteration-count;}` In case you are unfamiliar with '@keyframes', you work with percents of an animation phase. A similar effect has been made with this [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/bmorelli25/pen/VzXJzN) or you can look at keyframes in depth with either [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) ***or*** [Mozilla CDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

I hope this was helpful in your endeavors. 😁

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but it is not that i actually want. Please go through powerpoint 365 bounce effect, in which object bounce and move left to right smoothly.

Comment: Hey, it has been a while, if you have not found an answer yet, I think I have a method that could get the effect. The animation platform Green Sock is really robust in its animations. Read up on it, if you haven't before. (You'll have to pay if you are developing a site to be posted online with purchases.

Comment: Although, if you have NO basic knowledge of JavaScript/ JQuery, you can watch their really helpful tutorials on YouTube.